# Chinese character strings transmitted between client and server garbled

Tags: java, c++, string, sockets, boost-asio

i'm writing a simple client/server program. Basically, the client sends a query string to the server and the server sends back an answer in the form of a character string, too. The server is written in C++ using the socket-based boost/asio library. The server is written on a Linux box (Fedora 25). The client is written in Java. Everything works except when I installed the client on a Windows machine when I noticed the query string (in Chinese) was garbled at the server end. Do not have this problem when client is also on Linux.

```
socket = new Socket(host, port);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println(inputStr);
resultStr = in.readLine();
```

Above is the client part java code. The server C++ code for receiving the query string is:

```
ProcessRequest(asio::streambuf& request){ 
std::string input = to_string(request);
std::cout << input << std::endl;
...
```

Here I noticed that when client was run from a windows machine, the received Chinese query string was all garbage.

Again, when client was run from a Linux box, no problem.

Comment: What encoding are you sending the data in? `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 0):

You should choose right Encoding for messages. In Java it is [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But how come I don't have that problem when both client and server are on Linux?

Comment: Windows "Unicode" is UTF-16LE, and each character is 2 or 4 bytes. Linux uses UTF-8, and each character is between 1 and 4 bytes.